# Intellij-idea not compiling changes in Java / Kotlin files

Tags: intellij-idea, compilation

I'm creating a desktop app in Java + Kotlin. It's running properly but suddenly the Intellij stopped running my changes.

Example: 
I run a `println('1')` and it runs ok. So, I change it to `println('2')` and it runs ok, but showing the last change `1`. But it's happening with everything in my code.

I tried to save all, re sync, re build, clean, nothing is helping. sometimes the IDE decides to compile, before starting to bother me again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "*. . . but showing the last change 1*"? It's just printing 1 still?

Comment: Yes, it's print the last change. Not the new one, as expected.

Comment: How are you running it? In a REPL? Through the terminal?

Comment: Directly from the IntelliJ run button.

Comment: @JonathanSilva Do you have Build action enabled in the Before launch section? Any errors in idea.log/build.log? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085.